# External high performing Tools to load MYSQL data

Tags: mysql, upload

I have almost a TB of data to be loaded to MYSQL database regularly once in a week.

The server used is of lower configuration and takes a long time for every upload.

Can anyone please suggest me a tool or efficient technology to handle this.

Comment: how are you curently loading the data?

Comment: We load thru LOAD infile command for 320 new tables created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a matter of efficiency.  No software will fix this.  Your problem is server and network.

1TB per week?  In a single instance of MySQL on an under-powered server?  With no sharding or replication?  I sincerely doubt that.

But if you must continue, maybe you should look into [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/).  Keep your data in the Hadoop file system.  You won't have to move it anywhere.  Use Hive for SQL and let map-reduce help with the processing.

Answer (score 1):

I personally found that `LOAD DATA INFILE` works best for me. Check it out: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html.

But as @duffymo said, if your server simply can't handle this, it doesn't matter how you upload data, it might not be physically possible to go faster (disks can write only this much data per second).